# Javascript possibly preventing css background images to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We are having some problems finding the source of background images not loading. As far as we know there have been no troubles with them loading prior to implementing eu cookie javascript function.

jsFiddle: (just the JS) http://jsfiddle.net/dx4MC/

For some reason, on occasions we cannot replicate (appears to be random) all background-images on a page will fail to load. Has anyone come across this before?

A possible thought was the js wasnt allowing the CSS to load fully, however no other styles have been affected, only the background images.

Comment: Are you sure they don't load? Isn't it rather something like `background-position` set to very large numbers, so you don't see them? You may check whether they have been requested and loaded in Firebug.

Comment: We have found that it is partially protruding so, the background image will display in a random block at one place and no where else, could it be a stacking issue?

Comment: are you sure this does not only happen to people that did / did not accept the policy? if it's connected to cookies, I'd start with that and try to make sure this does not happen one way or another (i.e. with cookies turned on/off and accepting/declining the policy)

Comment: also, have you tried putting the CSS itself to an external file rather than writing it out using JS?

Comment: as an aside, the cookie stuff is unnecessary if youre in the UK: http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2012/may/26/cookies-law-changed-implied-consent http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/~/media/documents/library/Privacy_and_electronic/Practical_application/cookies_guidance_v3.ashx

Comment: Can you show a sample that includes some HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
!important
```

in your css to override the javascript inline styling